# React-Native: How to make two versions apk for phones and tablet?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to make my app to scale on all devices, but I have a problem with the rescaling after the device exceeds 8 inches.

Is it possible to make two APK's, one for devices below 8' and one for bigger than 8' for the play store ?

I am not sure if I have to do this in the code somewhere or it's easy to do with the Google Play store settings ? I have never uploaded before. Same question for the iOS platform.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create two APK but then you need to upload your app to play store(android) or app store(ios) with two different bundleid(different names of app). I think thats not good practise(it means like uploading two different apps).

I would suggest you to improve your flexbox styling, so that you don't need to face scaling problem.

Comment: My problem is with the Images. I cannot make them retain aspect ratio. But they remain small and focused.

Comment: then i think, you should ask question about how to handle images scalling in react-native....

Comment: i think i have solved your querry about 2 different apk.... if you want to ask more.. don't hesitate... if you feel fine.please accept the answer

Comment: Any way to make it with the same name ? I really hoped google play or the app store have some kind integrated settings to choose for which devices, which version of the apk it can appear in stores.

Comment: sorry mate... On appstore or playstore ... you must have unique bundleid1(app name) for registering.